# Can't create a folder or copy a file to Google Drive - Shared Folder from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I am on Ubuntu 21.04. I am connected to my Google Drive through Online Accounts and I can access the drive through Nautilus.

The problem is I can't write on those Shared folders. The Error message is like this "Error when creating directory  There was an error creating the directory in google-drive://..... Target Object doesn't exist."

The issue is only happening with Google Drive > Shared folders but not on My Folders under the same Google Drive.

Comment: Same problem here, Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome.

Comment: Same problem here on latest Archlinux with Gnome 40.4.0